# Query to filter data based conditions in child table

Tags: linq

Based on the following tables, I would like to get all the Department names which has all its employees as active (Active == 1). I am specifically looking for a LINQ query.

Based on the below data, only department "Z" should be listed.

```
EmpId,EmpName,DepartmentId,Active
"1",    "A",        "1",    "0"
"2",    "B",        "1",    "1"
"3",    "C",        "1",    "1"
"4",    "D",        "2",    "0"
"5",    "E",        "3",    "1"
"6",    "F",        "3",    "1"


DeptId,DeptName
"1",    "X"
"2",    "Y"
"3",    "Z"
```

A SQL query for realizing the above is as follows:

```
SELECT `DeptName` FROM `Department` d JOIN `Employee` e ON d.`DeptId` = e.`DepartmentId` WHERE `Active` = 1 AND `DepartmentId` NOT IN 
(SELECT `DepartmentId` FROM `Department` d JOIN `Employee` e ON d.`DeptId` = e.`DepartmentId` WHERE `Active` = 0) GROUP BY `DeptName`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's a link from department to employees:

```
Departments.Where(dep => dep.Employees.All(emp => (emp.Active == "1")));
```

Otherwise (link from employees to department)

```
Employees.Where(emp => (emp.Active == "1")).
          Select(emp => emp.Department).
          Distinct();
```